# What is the Android Studio's architecture?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, adb, adt

After downloading `AS` from http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html i get error that my `JAVA_HOME` is not valid. Where could we find any information if AndroidStudio is `x64` or `x86` architecture to set proper `jdk`?

Regards

Comment: I ask about android studio not windows.

Comment: Nope, you dont have to install the same jdk as your system. x64 system  can handle x64 and x86 jdk unlike to x86 system which afaik works only with x86 java. But my question is about android studio, not jdk or even windows... JAVA_HOME is set properly, other tools which require it works perfectly.

Comment: well...if you know everything i cant help you...i have installed AS in WIN and linux, both working well.... there is only one AS version, and i installed JDK according to my system...thats it... but you know it better..so do it ;)

Comment: So is it on windows or some other platform?

Comment: Android Studio (being based on ItelliJ IDEA) contains binaries for both architectures, but the default shortcuts it creates are for the x64 one if your system supports it.

Comment: Adding specificity to what @corsair992 said, you'll notice that there exists `studio.exe` and `studio64.exe`. Run the proper one for your system.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread, but I think the issue is that the java jdk setting are in a different place then you expect them, at least after v1

From the Menu Bar, goto `File > Project Structure > SDK Location`

and you can set the path to the `JDK Location` (whatever version you have installed) there

Answer (score 0):

[image: set user variable like this]
 variable name : JAVA_HOME

variabel value : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\

[image: set system variable like this]
variable name : Path

variabel value : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\

[and also if not working delete java folder form program files and downlaod it again](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/indexes/downloads/index.html)